# Count transactions within a month only once

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a situations like below:

I have two database tables. The first table, which I will call TB1 contains all the salaries that the client credits & also the date when the transaction is made.
The second table, which I will call TB2, contains all the products the client has in the bank.
My purpose is to find the number of salaries the client has got before the date he/she got a product (OVERDRAFT in my case) in our bank.
Till now, everything works fine and I have made the query to extract the necessary data.
The only problem, is that I need to improve the query. So, if a certain client has got more than 1 salary (for example every 15 days) within the same month of the same year, the salary is counted only once.
How can I do that PLEASE?

The query is like below:

```
SELECT TB1.customer_id, COUNT(TB1.customer_id)
FROM table_1 TB1
JOIN
( SELECT TB2.CUSTOMER_ID, TB2.OD_START_DATE
  FROM table_2 TB2
  JOIN table_2 TB2_MAX
  ON TB2.CUSTOMER_ID = TB2_MAX.CUSTOMER_ID
  HAVING TB2.od_start_date = MAX(TB2.od_start_date)
  GROUP BY TB2.customer_id, TB2.od_start_date
) TB2
ON TB1.CUSTOMER_ID = TB2.CUSTOMER_ID
WHERE TB1.DATE_FROM < TB2.OD_START_DATE
GROUP BY TB1.CUSTOMER_ID
```

PS: DATE_FROM field contains the date when the transaction is made, while OD_START_DATE field contains the date when the LATEST product is opened.

Answer (score 1):

JOIN in your inner query is redundant. You simply need a MAX date for each customer.
In your outer query you should be counting the DATE_FROM, and not Customer_Id. Since you want to count only once for transactions in a month, Convert DATE_FROM to year month combination and use DISTINCT to count only once.

```
SELECT TB1.customer_id, COUNT(DISTINCT TO_CHAR(TB1.DATE_FROM,'YYYYMM'))
FROM table_1 TB1
JOIN
( SELECT CUSTOMER_ID, MAX(OD_START_DATE) AS OD_START_DATE
  FROM table_2
  GROUP BY customer_id
) TB2
ON TB1.CUSTOMER_ID = TB2.CUSTOMER_ID
WHERE TB1.DATE_FROM < TB2.OD_START_DATE
GROUP BY TB1.CUSTOMER_ID
```

Comment: Thank you Noel, I didn't do the exact thing you said, but the COUNT(DISTINCT TO_CHAR(TB1.DATE_FROM,'YYYYMM')) saved my life :) THANK YOU SO MUCH

Comment: can you please show me how to do that? I did vote for the solution.

Comment: Just click on the tick mark next to the answer. http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers